# How to split numbers into separate digits in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Does anyone know a fairly simple way to split numbers of various length into separate digits and then manipulate each digit? Could probably do it in Excel itself, but thinking a macro would be nicer as I am only interested in a list of results that live up to a few criteria.
Example:
1234 is split into 1, 2, 3, and 4. Each of these is then squared and the sum of the squares is returned as a number (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 30)
Now only if the outcome can be divided by a chosen number, say 3, the macro will fill a cell with the given number and it's corresponding outcome: A1 = 1234, A2 = 30.
It will do this for all i = 1 to 10000, creating a list of only the numbers that fulfills the constraint.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the Macro in Excel VBA to do this or just a pointer in a direction?

This may not be the most efficient way but it is one way.

Go through the range of numbers and for each number convert to a String  e.g.     sValue = Trim(Str(I))

then for each Digit in LEN(sValue) you get the Value and Square it

e.g. 
    For J = 1 To Len(sValue)
        Result = Result + (Val(Mid(sText, J, 1)) ^ 2)
    Next J

Once you have a Result, perform your requested criteria and confirm it is a whole number (for example)
    e.g.
        (Result / Divisor) = Round(Result / Divisor, 0)

and put your results into the required cells.
Repeat for as many iterations as you require (e.g. 10000)

Here is a sample I just made up and I think it works okay for your example (gives 3711 rows of answers), just change the Const values for your requirements.

```
Sub SplitNumber()
Const StartRange = 1
Const EndRange = 10000
Const Divisor = 3
Const InputCol = 1
Const ResultCol = 2

Dim StartRow, Result As Integer
Dim sValue As String

StartRow = 1
I = StartRange
CurrentRow = StartRow

While I <= EndRange
    sValue = Trim(Str(I))
    Result = 0
    If Len(sValue) > 1 Then
        For J = 1 To Len((sValue))
            Result = Result + (Val(Mid(sValue, J, 1)) ^ 2)
        Next J
    Else
        Result = Val(sValue) ^ 2
    End If
    If (Result / Divisor) = Round(Result / Divisor, 0) Then
        Cells(CurrentRow, InputCol) = I
        Cells(CurrentRow, ResultCol) = Result
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    End If
    I = I + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply.
Beautiful code, just what I needed.The Trim(), Str() and Val() were new to me, so exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Reason was, that I came across the Munchausen numbers today, so out of pure curiosity I wanted to see if I could have a macro test it.
Had to change a few Dim's to Double, and raise the numbers to themselves instead of 2, but that was all the tweeking needed.
Oh, and need a new computer too. It didn't like it when I changed EndRange to 1E+16 :)

Good job, nice to learn some new code, thanks again.

Comment: yes, I did think about what would happen if you had large numbers and then thought of the example you gave and decided you could figure out the other stuff ... glad it helped ... the Text/Num conversion functions are pretty old school but then so am I :-)

Comment: Please feel free to up or down vote my answer as you see fit as it is hard enough to get points here :-) Cheers

Comment: Would if I could, but new here, so need points myself first ;)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's how to do it without VBA:

1. Enter this array formula in `B1` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

   `{=SUMSQ(1*MID(ROW(),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(ROW()))),1))}`
2. Enter this formula in `A1`:

   `=IF(MOD(B1,3)=0,ROW(),0)`
3. Fill down for as many rows as you like. 10,000 in your case.
4. Filter to hide values of `0` in column `A` OR copy / paste values and then sort `A` and delete all rows with a value of `0`.